# Joomla robots.txt

Tags: joomla, robots.txt

I have a robots.txt in my Joomla root Directory which says:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

I dont know much about robots.txt Files but these are all directories in the root. So that means Google doesnt crawl all of these? But isnt that bad? I want the Sites content to be indexed or whatever...

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google does not crawl these directories and no, that's not a bad thing. You do not want Google to do this as these directories are not supposed to be directly accessed. Joomla has it's main **index.php** files in the root directory where **everything** gets pushed to. The only things that will get crawled are your menu items which you assign your component to.

Answer (score 1):

No, **Google** doesn't crawl these directories, but according to this article:

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/allow-googlebot-access-javascript-css-optimal-rankings/119113/

You should allow some directories that have **CSS** and **Javascript** files for **Googlebot** to crawl.

So change your **robots.txt** file like this :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
# Disallow: /modules/    <-------- Commented out using #
# Disallow: /plugins/    <-------- Commented out using #
# Disallow: /templates/    <-------- Commented out using #
Disallow: /tmp/
```

and if you want to allow a specific path, you should use this syntax :

```
Allow: /plugins/system/jch_optimize/assets2/
Allow: /plugins/system/jch_optimize/assets/
```